# How to install OpenCV on Solo 3dr

Tags: python, opencv, dronekit-python, dronekit

How to install OpenCV or Python-OpenCV on 3dr Solo computer (Linux 3dr_solo 3.10.17 armv71)?

Is there any .tar or .rpm package available for download?

Comment: Have you checked http://opencv.org/ ? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Solo has a package manager, so you can run `smart install python-opencv` to install opencv and python bindings.  But first you will need to install `smart`, and you will need to expand the root filesystem. Instructions for all of this can be found at http://dev.3dr.com/